# Помогите решить ошибку с editText android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

У меня в приложении есть два editText и информацию из одного мне нужно конвертировать в int из string. Я пробовал разные методы:

```
String log = loginEditText.getText().toString();
Integer login = Integer.parseInt(log);
```

до этого варианта пробовал valueof() но тоже выскакивает ошибка, то есть по факту из-за одного поля для ввода я не могу запустить приложение.метод в котором использую эти два поля:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        loginEditText = findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();
        error = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password);
        passwordEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        String log = loginEditText.getText().toString();
        Integer login = Integer.parseInt(log);
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        final AuthRequestBody body = new AuthRequestBody(login, password);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://0")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiService api = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        final Call<AuthResponse> call = api.authUser(body);



        Button mEmailSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            AuthResponse serverAnswer = response.body();
                            assert serverAnswer != null;
                            if (serverAnswer.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                                // Авторизация прошла успешно
                                // можно, например, перейти на другую активити
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                // Авторизация не прошла
                                error.setText("Error");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
                //attemptLogin();
                messages();
            }
        });
        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    }
```

вот код ошибки:

```
07-11 07:32:02.086 1929-1929/com.example.developer_4.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.myapplication, PID: 1929
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.myapplication/com.example.developer_4.myapplication.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
        at com.example.developer_4.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:96)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

если я правильно понял то я вроде как передаю пустую строку но по факту я ведь еще ничего не успел передать. Если кто знает в чем проблема то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Где находится приведенный код?

Comment: не понял, что значит где? где я использую его?

Comment: Да. В каком методе, классе и т.д.

Comment: подправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы поняли совершенно правильно - в метод `Integer.parseInt(log);` передается пустая строка. А пустая она потому что в поле `loginEditText` ничего не содержится. Приложение выполняет `onCreate()` сразу после старта активити, как и положено, и не ждет, когда в поле ввода что-то появится. Вам нужно перенести обработку информации туда, где она должна обрабатываться - в `onCLick()` кнопки, например.

PS. Судя по всему, в поле `loginEditText` должен быть имейл. А вы хотите достать оттуда целое число. Нет ли здесь ошибки?

Comment: ну я как-бы использую стандартный экран для логина, но мне дали для входа id которое в int и я пытаюсь этот экран подстроить под свои цели)))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko,если ответ решил вашу проблему, примите его (галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: ответ то помог, но создалась другая проблема)))) как всегда короче